# YouTube API chromeless player token expiration

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, token, chromeless

### *Summary*

I have a Youtube API chromeless player in my Flex/AS3 application. Sometimes I need the player to play movies from Youtube continuously (non-stop).

### *Issues*

- After playing for something like 12 or more hours the API token which was generated by the first player initialization request is getting expired.

  ```
   http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&modestbranding=1&autoplay=0
  ```

  And the issue here is that the API call **loadVideoById** which is called again after the token is expired can't start playing video, because the token is not getting renewed automatically.
- After playing our playlist (each item is getting played by calling to **loadVideoById**) for something like 4-5 or more hours the video sometimes starts to play and suddenly getting stuck. While no error event is dispatched.

### *Known Solutions*

- So for the first issue the solution is to renew the token each 12 hours by unloading the player and loading it again using the API call:

  ```
   http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&modestbranding=1&autoplay=0
  ```
- For the second issue there are no ideas. Need your help.

### *The relevant source code*

```
private function CreateYoutubePlayerSWF():void {
    ...
    theYoutubeLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
    theYoutubeLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&modestbranding=1&autoplay=0"));
    ...
}

private function PlayPendingVideo():void {
    ...         
    theYoutubePlayer.loadVideoById(videoWaitingToPlayInfo.videoWaitingToPlay);
    ...
}
```

### *Requests & Responses*

When the player stops playing this is what I get in the fiddler:

```
"request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "http://www.youtube.com/get_video?cpn=Lj5HaLu7MzS5kG-T&fmt=35&splay=1&t=vjVQa1PpcFNwMVrYUDFOTTG-7co1uJFo3oyrB-qoP_k=&video_id=j-vJJSqw5Q4&eurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwatchitoo.com%2Fiframe.php%3Fid%3Dwwa-154%26scale%3Dfalse%26layout%3D14&asv=3&el=embedded&ps=chromeless&ptk=youtube_none&noflv=1",
      ...
      "queryString": [
        {
          "name": "cpn",
          "value": "Lj5HaLu7MzS5kG-T"
        },
        {
          "name": "fmt",
          "value": "35"
        },
        {
          "name": "splay",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "t",
          "value": "vjVQa1PpcFNwMVrYUDFOTTG-7co1uJFo3oyrB-qoP_k"
        },
        {
          "name": "video_id",
          "value": "j-vJJSqw5Q4"
        },
        {
          "name": "eurl",
          "value": "http%3A%2F%2Fwatchitoo.com%2Fiframe.php%3Fid%3Dwwa-154%26scale%3Dfalse%26layout%3D14"
        },
        {
          "name": "asv",
          "value": "3"
        },
        {
          "name": "el",
          "value": "embedded"
        },
        {
          "name": "ps",
          "value": "chromeless"
        },
        {
          "name": "ptk",
          "value": "youtube_none"
        },
        {
          "name": "noflv",
          "value": "1"
        }
```

---

```
    "response": {
      "status": 410,
      "statusText": "Gone",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Date",
          "value": "Wed, 26 Jun 2013 16:32:37 GMT"
        },
        {
          "name": "X-Content-Type-Options",
          "value": "nosniff"
        },
        {
          "name": "Server",
          "value": "Apache"
        },
        {
          "name": "X-Frame-Options",
          "value": "SAMEORIGIN"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "video/x-flv"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Length",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Expires",
          "value": "Tue, 27 Apr 1971 19:44:06 EST"
        }
```